# phpcassa fail connect to server

Tags: cassandra, phpcassa

I install cassandra on ubuntu, set in conf file

**listen_address: 200.166.107.170**

**rpc_address: 213.186.117.170**

**rpc_port: 9160**

then i try run this php code from other machine

**CassandraConn::add_node('200.166.107.170', 9160);**

**$users = new CassandraCF('Keyspace1', 'Users');**

**$users->insert('1', array('email' => 'hoan.tonthat@gmail.com', 'password' => 'test'));**

and as result have this

**Fatal error:** Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Could not connect to a cassandra server' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\phpcassa.php:85 Stack trace: #0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\phpcassa.php(283): CassandraConn::get_client() #1 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cassandra_test.php(31): CassandraCF->insert('1', Array) #2 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\phpcassa.php on line 85

what can be a cause of this error? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you are using the version of PHPCassa distributed by *thobbs*:

- https://github.com/thobbs/phpcassa
- Tutorial on how to get started:  http://thobbs.github.com/phpcassa/tutorial.html

From the tutorial:

```
 $servers = array("192.168.2.1:9160");
 $pool = new ConnectionPool("Keyspace1", $servers);
 $column_family = new ColumnFamily($pool, 'ColumnFamily1');
```

Failing this, what version of Apache Cassandra are you using?

** Update **

Turns out that you are trying to connect to Cassandra on the LISTEN_ADDRESS and not the RPC_ADDRESS.  213.186.117.170:9160 would be the one you should connect on and not the other which is used for cassandra - cassandra communication.

Comment: Cassandra version 0.8.1, phpcassa downloaded from https://github.com/hoan/phpcassa

Comment: Right, that version will **NOT** work with Cassandra 0.8.1 ... follow my instructions above ..

Comment: i try, same problem, with cassandra-cli connect is success

Comment: ok, a set listen address 127.0.0.1 and try connect to rpc address, but same error

Comment: netstat -an  ... 9160 is on what ip?  webserver with phpcassa is on what ip?

Comment: i already find out what a problem, there is some ubuntu network previlegies problem. I run http server with php right on machine where cassandra installed, all work perfect, Thanks!